# Why is iOS simulator displaying blank screen when I rotate device?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, simulator

Getting through some introductory swift and playing with Xcode and I basically just have a page with some color squares, background color etc.  Doesn't do anything.   Problem is when I compile the code it will run in simulator just fine and show everything perfect, BUT when I rotate the device, everything disappears and it only gives me a blank white screen.   Rotating right or left does it.  The only view that shows it is the original upright view (for all iPhone devices that I tested on through the simulator).

Xcode 6.1.1 and iOS Simulator 8.1 are being used on my MacBook Air with OSX 10.9.5.

In the App general page, I have already checked under Deployment info that Landscape Right and Left are both checked on.   Storyboard is set on Any H and Any W.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and it has been pretty difficult searching since I'm still new to iOS development I'm not sure I'm using the right words or whatever because I can't find an answer.

Summary:

App displays properly in iOS Simulator, Portrait View but no other views work and will display blank white screen instead.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see if your views are actually being drawn and just off screen as others have suggested capture the view hierarchy. Go to 'debug' in the menu, then in 'view debugging' click capture view hierarchy. This will pause your app and create a 3D representation of all view on your screen which you can move around by clicking and dragging.

Are your views actually being drawn? If yes are they drawing off screen? If yes then you need to fix your constraints.

Comment: Great advice on using the `View Debugger` (link to docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html). This should always be the first step in trying to fix visual / autolayout issues.

Comment: @RoboticCat I've found it invaluable since I started using it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I played the app, iOS Simulator came up and the problem was there.  Then I went to Debug in xCode and clicked on capture view hierarchy - the image is there.  It is showing in iOS Simulator as well except the image is not rotating along with the device.   When I rotate the screen, it's like physically rotating the phone but not changing the picture to be in landscape at all.  So holding the phone landscape view means I see a portrait sideways.  Nothing is showing up in the little debug window at the bottom of xcode

Do I have another problem besides constraints?

Comment: When you capture the view hierarchy the app pauses execution. You need to press 'play' again. The play button is just above the console.

Comment: Thanks for dealing with my noob question :D    

I did it correctly to capture the view when my simulated device was in landscape view - nothing is drawn.   

Not sure how to proceed now since it shows me a blank white screen in the captured 3D view for debug.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are your auto layout constraints setup for the view?

Comment: Hopefully I'm giving the correct information here.  I realize that I had made the storyboard in Any W but Regular H (it says for portrait iphone and ipads).   Not sure if that makes any difference.   

The screen is just a blue box with other boxes inside.  The blue one which is background I used the Pin to each side 0 (to stretch and fill the screen).   I also used the Align to center it vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @LittleBee Could you post a sample project? It's difficult to debug constraints talking about them like this.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do that, i'll try to figure it out and post a link to git as soon as I can.  So far I have pretty much only worked on the Main.Storyboard file in the view.   Would it be ok to just post that file somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the correct auto-layout `UIConstraint`s set in interface builder. Check the document outline view in interface builder and ensure that you have appropriate constraints set on each view.

Auto Layout issues occur when you create conflicting constraints, **when you don’t provide enough constraints**, or when the final layout contains a set of constraints that are ambiguous.

Check this Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH17-SW1) out, it will show you step by step how to resolve your (common) issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't set your constraints appropriately. Try setting the top and leading constraints for each of your views to something less than 320 (should cover all device sizes). Fix your warnings, then try again. I believe the views are simply off the screen.